# Partially sort array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have the following array:
`const arr = [-1, 9, 2, 5, 6, -1, 9, 8, -1, 4];`
I want to sort it partially without changing the place of `-1`. The output should be:
`expected = [-1, 2, 5, 6, 9, -1, 8, 9, -1, 4]`. How can I achieve this in JavaScript. I will be grateful for both brute-force and optimal (time) solution...

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: you need to show some sort of attempt at implementation.  fwiw, javascript arrays have built in comparator functions.  see.  Array.prototype.sort.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
arr = [-1, 9, 2, 5, 6, -1, 9, 8, -1, 4];

sorted=arr.reduce((acc,cv)=>{
  if(cv==-1) {
    acc.push([-1]);
    acc.push([]);
  }
  else {
    acc[acc.length-1].push(cv);
  }
  return acc;
},[[]])
.map(item=>item.sort((a,b)=>a-b))
.reduce((acc,cv)=>acc.concat(cv),[])

console.log(JSON.stringify(sorted));
```

Comment: You are welcome!
Note that I've edited the initial value to `[[]]`!!!

Comment: Note should be using numeric sort not default string sort. It's only working here since all the numbers are single digits